# How to unit test grails domain class that has a relational mapping?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-domain-class, domain-mapping

The output of my test gives `com.example.book.Book : null`. When I debug the test, `b` object is created with `"MyBook"` as its `name`. But since its has a static mapping `belongsTo`, the test fails. How do I make this work. When I comment the `belongsTo` mapping in the Books.groovy, the test passes. So how do I test Domain classes with mappings. Should I instantiate a `Library` object and add a `Book` object to it? But that doesn't make testing the domain class in isolation as it is meant to be in a unit test, does it?

Below is my code.

Domains:

```
//Book.groovy
package com.example.book

class Book {
    static constraint = {
        name blank: false, size: 2..255, unique: true
    }
    static belongsTo = [lib: Library]
    String name
}

//Library.groovy
package com.example.library

class Library {
    static hasMany = [book: Book, branch: user: User]
    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
        place blank: false
    }
    String name
    String place
}
```

Unit tests:

```
//BookUnitTests.groovy
package com.example.book

import grails.test.*

class BookUnitTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        mockForConstraintsTests(Book)
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testPass() {
        def b = new Book(name: "MyBook")
        assert b.validate()
    }
}
```

Test Output:

```
Failure:  testPass(com.example.book.BookUnitTests)
|  Assertion failed: 

assert b.validate()
       | |
       | false
       com.example.book.Book : null

       at com.example.book.BookUnitTests.testPass(BookUnitTests.groovy:17)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way you have this set up the Book cannot exist without a Library. You will have to create a Library and assign the book to it.

Whether using `belongsTo` makes sense depends on your requirements. Do you really need to save the library and have all the books get saved as a result?

Comment: I can't change the domain classes. Thanks for the answer. It made me think in the right direction. I have to create a `Library` object and assign it to the `Book` object during the initialization of Book object like: `def l = new Library(name: "a", place: "p"); def b = new Book(name: "myBook", lib: l);` and then do `b.validate()` which passes the test. Phew!! Spent whole day figuring it out. The grails guys could have documented it.

Comment: Should all the unit testing for Book go in LibraryUnitTests or should it be spread between two test classes?

Comment: @Allison: for integration tests with the current design you're stuck. for non-persistence-related unit tests you can do whatever makes sense.