# Change domain class mapping for testing on Grails 2.3.0

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class with a mapping clause that looks like this

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'DB'
    table 'manager.dbo.table_name'
}
```

It is working flawless on my app, I even have a *@Resource* annotation. But this custom mapping is not working for h2 testing. I was [looking at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823650/how-to-unit-test-grails-domain-class-that-has-a-relational-mapping) but it doesn't answer my question (I cannot find a place to insert a replace code before hibernate mapping is run)

How can I change the mapping for a Testing environment? Or, even easier, how can I prevent hibernate to take into consideration those classes? Is it possible?